# How do I customize the URL users get sent to after logging out?

Tags: c#, servicestack

I am using ServiceStack, and sending a `GET` request to `../api/auth/logout`.

The logout is happening as expected, but afterwards the user gets redirected to `../../#s=-1`, and I can't figure out how to customize this URL.

Can somebody point me in the right direction?

Thanks very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `/auth/logout` service redirects to the first existing route in the following order:

1. The `Continue` parameter if set, e.g. `?continue=/path`
2. The Referrer Url on the Users Session i.e. `IAuthUserSession.ReferrerUrl`
3. The `Referer` HTTP Header (i.e. redirects back to where it came from)
4. The `CallbackUrl` of the first AuthProvider registered

For more details here's the [source code for the Logout action](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/9a4afa19da452a148d05c2d0964f1703ec451a22/src/ServiceStack/Auth/AuthProvider.cs#L70-L86) that does this.

Comment: An answer from Mr Servicestack himself, awesome, thanks very much :)